# How to judge if a django model object is exactly a BaseClass instance?

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance, model

I have a `ParentModel` model in django:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):

    field_a = models.IntegerField()
    field_b = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_parent'
```

And I defined a super class `ChildModel` after that:

```
class ChildModel(ParentModel):

    field_c = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_child'
```

The above will create two tables in my database, which we called `table_parent` and `table_child`.

So, now I create two instances:

```
first_obj = ParentModel.objects.create(...) # id=1
second_obj = ChildModel.objects.create(...) # id=2
```

And it will create two objects, which totally inserted two rows in `table_parent` and one row in `table_child`.

Now, if I fetch the instances, but both create from `ParentModel`:

```
first_obj = ParentModel.objects.get(id=1) # id=1
second_obj = ParentModel.objects.create(id=2) # id=2
```

So, in fact, the `second_obj` is a `ChildModel` instance. I want a neat way to judge it, like:

```
first_obj.is_exact_base() # I want it to be True
second_obj.is_exact_base() # I want it to be False
```

More, I may have more than one Super Classes of `ParentModel`, I want it can work well in that case.

---

My effort:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def is_exact_base(self):
        try:
            child = self.childmodel
            return False
        except:
            return True
```

This method can work, but too much redundancy, is there a **best** implementation for my problem?

Comment: What do you mean with too much redundancy?

Comment: @Jonathan I must manually define a function in the model class, and have a try-except in it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a complete minimum working example? I've never used Django and I don't even see what you try to do.

From a python programmer perspective (sorry, I'm convinced that I did not understand everything), if you want to know if objectA is an instance of BaseClass, what you want is:

```
isinstance(objectA, BaseInstance)
```

If this cannot be applied to your case, then Python has no way to tell the difference. Just like if you do:

```
def f(a, b):
    a.append(b)

def g(a, b):
    a.append(b)

a = []
f(a, 0)
g(a, 1)

>>> print(a)
[0, 1]
```

You have absolutely no way of telling which function appended what.

So if you are in this case, you need either to add a new column to your table which would contain that information or the object you are writing should contain that information.

Comment: This is a django issue, so I think your answer doesn't help

Comment: Maybe but nobody cared to answer. **And** Django or not, this is Python. Django is not some kind of plugin that would change how Python behaves: it's only a Python module built on top of Python. What I have written is not Django-specific but Python-specific so it should apply to Django as well.

Comment: If the 'objects' in your tables are just raw numbers, you can't do anything to know what wrote them except by writing this information somewhere yourself. If what you put in your tables are serialized class instances, then you could define different classes and use `isinstance`. There are maybe Django built-ins for this but they should go down to one of the two methods I provided.